# Why Android Studio delete all the files on git commit?

Tags: git, github, android-studio

I recently migrated from Eclipse to Android Studio. Now I have all my project working but directory structure has changed in Android Studio so I have to commit this changes to my GitHub repository so I did:

- Copied `.git` folder from Eclipse Project to Android Studio Project
- VCS -> Git -> Add to VCS

So now I have a my Git repository and I can see all the changes I did in Eclipse in `Changes View`. Now to commit the new project structure:

- VCS -> Commit Changes

A new windows is opened with the changes and I see Android Studio want to delete ALL my files except 2, one I modified on Android Studio and the other a .iml file.

[image]

So when I commit all the files of my project are deleted from my git repository instead of committing almost everything and delete some folders due to directory structure change . Why this happens? Is it a bug? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I get it working correctly, the procedure on Linux would be:

1. Download and install [gitg](https://github.com/jessevdk/gitg). On Debian based distributions you can install it with `sudo apt-get install gitg`
2. Commit the changes using `gitg` (it will commit the changes as it should without the error in Android Studio)
3. Restart Android Studio

Now Android Studio will work as expected with GIT.